# the result of Query mismatch In a MongoDB Shard environment,

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks, mongodb-replica-set

I Configured it like this:

```
* configDB 1
* configDB 2
* configDB 3
* Mongos
* mongod (cluster_1)
* mongod (cluster_2)

shardkey : num (field)
shardkeyrange: 1~5 -> cluster1
shardkeyrange: 6~10 -> cluster2
```

I inserted 10 data in db (mongos) with the query below

```
db.A.insert({"num":1});
db.A.insert({"num":2});
db.A.insert({"num":3});
db.A.insert({"num":4});
db.A.insert({"num":5});
db.A.insert({"num":6});
db.A.insert({"num":7});
db.A.insert({"num":8});
db.A.insert({"num":9});
db.A.insert({"num":10});
```

find query, in mongod(cluster_1, cluster_2)

```
db.A.find({}).count; // cluster_1
> 5
db.A.find({}).count; //cluster_2
> 3
```

Expected value:

```
>5
>5
```

It can be seen that 5 data are stored in each shard server.
But when I queried with each cluster, cluster_1 has 5 data and cluster_2 has 3 data.
This Does not always happen. This phenomenon seems to happen occasionally.

**Is there a situation in which a similar phenomenon could occur?
Can this happen when a specific operation is being performed in the db? Like Chunk Migration..
I would like to know various situations or causes that can cause the above phenomenon**

Comment: Add the queries you ran and their results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `.count` method is known to be inaccurate because it only checks the metadata and doesn't actually count the documents. This method is deprecated in recent versions of MongoDB.

A few things you can try instead:

- `db.A.countDocuments()` - this function only exists in the newest releases
- `db.A.count({num:{$gt:0}})` - A filter with `count` will cause it to read the documents and count them
- `db.A.find({}).itcount()` - this will fetch all of the documents from the server, pass them to the driver/shell and count them on the client side